# Bash prompt in OS X terminal broken

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I am using bash in os X Terminal app, and my custom $PS1 breaks when I scroll through my history.

```
PS1="${BLUE}\u${CYAN}@${RED}\h${BLUE}\w\n\[${red}\$${NC}\]"
```

also tried 
    PS1="${BLUE}\u${CYAN}@${RED}\h${BLUE}\w\r\n[${red}\$${NC}]"

The problem seems to be in the newline.  I have used this bash prompt on Slackware no prob.

Comment: default mac bash or macports bash?

Comment: how is $BLUE defined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the [ and ] arond every escape sequence; do $BLUE and the like include these? If not, they need to be bracketed with these calls.

Comment: seems that is needed on the last line.  not really required on a previous line.

Comment: for others like me to whom "you need the [ and ] around every escape sequence" doesn't mean much, what you need is: if you had (like me): `PS1="\e[0;32m\w \$\e[m "` you need: `PS1="\[\e[0;32m\]\w \$\[\e[m\] "`

Comment: Note, in modern MacOS, when using `zsh`, the escape sequence is not `\[...\]`, but `%{...%}`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid such 'escaping' difficulties as you prompt needs evole to be more complex, this should be a skeleton to start growing on:

```
function _my_prompt ()
{ 
  # magic goes here
  my_prmpt=.... 
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='_my_prompt'
PS1="[\$my_prmpt] \$"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem when logging on remote (debian) systems. As the escaped values in .bashrc all were nicely bracketed, I did some googling and discovered that the cause might be differences in window size on the local and the remote system. Adding

shopt -s checkwinsize

to .bashrc on the remote systems has fixed the problem for me.

Source: http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=17068

Answer (score 0):

If the problem seems to be with the newline, try putting \r\n instead of just \n and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem (on OS X) with your PS1.
If I remove the `\[` and `\]`

```
PS1="${BLUE}\u${CYAN}@${RED}\h${BLUE}\w\n${red}\$${NC}"
```

this works fine. Are the sqare brackets needed? I've never used them, but from [the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt):

> `\[`
>       Begin a sequence of non-printing characters. This could be used to
>   embed a terminal control sequence into
>   the prompt.
>
> `\]`
>       End a sequence of non-printing characters.

Comment: I tried this, but when i use the prevous commad keys, i get some residue

millermj@Leonidas~
$find ./ -na

Answer (score 0):

I have now tried

```
PS1="${BLUE}\u${CYAN}@${RED}\h${BLUE}\w${RED}\r\n\$\[${blue}\]"
```

Which seems to work 
The brackets needed to make previous commands work.