# How to get rid of "refs/bisect/bad" branches in Git

Tags: git, git-bisect

I have the following in my `~/.gitconfig` *(this is only here to help you understand what I'm looking at)*:

```
[alias]
    lg = log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%Cred%h %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset - %s %C(yellow)%d %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

When I do a `git log`, it shows me the full commit tree with branch names and stuff. Yesterday I initiated a `git bisect` and today I see there is a `refs/bisect/bad` branch in the output of my log.

**What exactly is the `refs/bisect/bad` branch and how do I get rid of it?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you're using `git bisect`, it uses `refs/bisect/bad` to track the last bad commit.  (That ref is updated when you do `git bisect bad`.)

I suspect that what's happened here is that you got to the end of the bisect, and it reported the first bad commit, but you never ended the bisection with `git bisect reset`, which would clean up the refs that it created.  You can still run that command, and it'll take you back to where you were before starting the bisections - however, I'd make sure that your work is committed and git status is clean before doing so, just to avoid any possible confusion.

If you use `__git_ps1` in your bash prompt, it will helpfully note that you're still in a bisection by outputting `(9dad0bb...)|BISECTING`.  I discussed `__git_ps1` a bit in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050377/broken-bash-prompt-wrap-line/5051169#5051169), which might be helpful.

Comment: In relatively recent versions of Git, you can also use `git bisect reset HEAD` to avoid switching commits.

Answer (score 13):

That's a pointer for commit marked as bad during bisect. You can run

> git bisect reset

or manually remove the pointer from .git/refs/bisect (but I don't recommend that)